# Problem on physical interpretation of divergence of curl of a vector zero

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields

Curl of a vector field A is non-zero. So that means that the vector which has curl or rotates does not diverge does not spread. So if we take A as the velocity.  Then the curl would be circulation per unit area. Then does it mean that when a fluid rotates it does not spread?

Comment: Why do you think that a vector field with a non-zero curl must have $0$ divergence?

Comment: The divergence of the curl of a vector is not the same as the divergence of the vector.

Comment: @AaronStevens I am saying a divergence of curl of a vector .

Comment: @LonelyProf can you interpret the problem physically in my scenario. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you are mixing up the divergence of the vector and the divergence of the curl of the vector.

Let's say we have a vector $\boldsymbol{A}$. Then, as you have noted, 
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot(\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{A})=0$$

But this is looking at the divergence of the curl of the vector.

If you want to talk about how the vector field "spreads out" we want to look at the divergence of the vector itself $$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}$$

This quantity does not necessarily have to be $0$ even when the curl $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{A}$ is non-zero.

In other words, it is possible to have a vector field with, as you put it, both "circulation" and "spreading out". To determine this all you need to do is calculate the divergence and curl separately, not the divergence of the curl (which is always $0$).

Comment: I always thought the idealized (2-d) flow around a whirlpool (or tornado/hurricane) was irrotational, and all the vorticity was fixed in the core (funnel/eye).

Comment: Aaron,  I think this formatting is more elegant  
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot}\left(\boldsymbol{\nabla
\times} \mathbf{A}\right)=0
$$

Comment: @Frobenius Always helping with the formatting tips :) thanks haha

Comment: Now I must up-vote it, haha !!!

Comment: @Frobenius Hmm maybe I should poorly format my answers at first more often

Comment: Giving nice answers must be our priority, then well-formatting is the next priority.